# Fiddler 2 Wipes My Internet Explorer Proxy Settings

Tags: internet-explorer, fiddler, proxy-server

I just started using Fiddler 2 to create request objects for REST,JSON, and SOAP based services that I have been creating. It has worked great so far.

The problem came when I attempted to use some of my company resources through Internet Explorer.  I was getting some sort of a DNS error, which I realized was happening because my proxy settings were getting wiped every time I open fiddler (IE6 and IE8). Does anyone know what Fiddler might be "fiddling" with here that would cause such a strange problem.

More info: This is happening on an Virtual PC VM running Windows XP. The exact stuff that is being blanked resides in the Tools->Internet Options->Connections->LAN Settings window. Both checkboxes there were checked and the fields in the Advanced window were populated.  Afterwards, all were blanked.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Fiddler changes your proxy settings on startup and reverts them back to what they were before you started when Fiddler is closed.

However, that doesn't really explain your problem, because when Fiddler is running it will use your old proxy server as an upstream proxy, and when you shut it down, it reverts the settings back to what they were before.

If you don't want to use Fiddler with IE, uncheck the "Act as system proxy" checkbox inside Tools / Fiddler Options; note that you'll need to manually configure your application or framework (e.g. .NET) to use 127.0.0.1:8888 as a proxy though.

Comment: Thanks Eric for writing such an awesome program btw

Comment: Does it use all of your prior proxy settings for the upstream proxy? In my case, I see that it has the proxy address in the Gateway line on the about window, but it still doesn't seem to get to some internal sites (which makes testing hard). We do have several proxy exclusions etc - I just want to be sure I am not missing something.

Comment: Yes, Fiddler adopts all of your prior proxy settings. What does "doesn't seem to get to some internal sites" mean more specifically?

Answer (score 4):

1.) Open a command prompt with Administrator priveleges

2.) Type NETSTAT -AB

3.) See if anything is running on Port 8888 already

If so, that is your problem. Change Fiddler to run off port 8889 (or next available port)

1.) Tools -> Fiddler Options -> Connections -> Fiddler listens on port -> 8889

Answer (score 2):

It's getting blanked out because Fiddler works by adding itself as a proxy instead of using your current proxy settings. That's how it intercepts all the traffic.

The good news is that, with a little configuration, you can configure Fiddler to act as a proxy AND use your manually configured corporate proxy as well:

[Fiddler Web Debugger - Configuring Clients](http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler/help/hookup.asp#Q-ManualChain)

Comment: You don't actually need any configuration-- that's the default. :-)

Comment: Even if the proxy isn't "automatically detected"? I was under the impression that if it was a manually configured proxy in the System Settings, it would have to be manually configured in Fiddler as well. Doh!

Answer (score 1):

Fiddler killed my ie connection but firefox connection remained....

I had an error "Fiddler: DNS Lookup for wwww.google.com.au failed. No such host is known"

I just fixed mine. I put "http://localhost:8888/VirtFolder/MyWebApp" into the url and it seemed to make the connection and IE start to work again.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your proxy is not pointing to a .PAC file. Fiddler does not "keep" this configuration when launched. Instead, type the actual proxy FQDN manually.